# Trying to move Docusign sandbox application to production. Invalid authentication request: The response type is not supported

Tags: docusignapi

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a node.js application running that will automatically create and send off PDF documents to Docusign. A user should not have to login manually to authenticate with Docusign to kick this process off.

I tested this in the sandbox environment using the token generator. I tried to request a review for production but it was denied because I hadn't made any successful API calls. I did make the API calls, but it seems none of them counted. I read somewhere that this was due to not going through the full flow of authentication? In any case, I'm trying to setup a proper authentication flow using JWT, which I believe is what I need for the automated server setup I'm using with Docusign.

**What I tried**

I started at the top and followed the steps here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

- I created an integration key in my sandbox account
- I defined a redirect URI
- I generated an RSA key pair
- In the details for that integration key I verified that authentication is set to Authorization Code Grant

Next step would be to request application consent. The documentation lists an example of https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com/callback

I replaced the client_id with the Integration Key that I setup as step one above and the redirect_uri with the one from step two above.

**What I'm seeing**

When I put that URL into my browser I instantly see an error on the page that says **'Invalid authentication request: The response type is not supported.'**. The documentation has a troubleshooting section with that error and it just says to make sure the integration key has authentication set to Authorization Code Grant and not Implicit Grant. I've done that but it hasn't helped.

**My Questions**

How can I get past that error to get the JWT token needed to support my app?

Is there a different authentication flow I should be using for my use case?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The JWT Grant workflow does sound correct for your use case.

When granting JWT consent, either response type (`code` or `token`) can be used. That said, you must use the one associated with the "User Application" setting on your integration key. If you're getting 'response type is not supported' when using `code`, either try changing your url's response type to `token`, or go to your integration key's setting and switch to 'Authorization Code Grant'

[image]

Comment: I will add that it is much better from an Information Security point-of-view to have your integration key set to use **Authorization Code Grant** than **Implicit grant**